# Storing time pricing information

Tags: mysql, schema

I have an application for a business customer and one of the new components is a time tracking system. The actual time tracking is done (pretty standard schema), but the structure this company uses to price their time is really odd and I don't know how to properly store this.

0-10 minutes: €16
10-15 minutes: €23
...
35-40 minutes: €58
more minutes: €63

In short, it's a completely irregular structure and while I could make a table with a column per interval, that seems to me like a smelly solution. A second table with a foreign key and `interval` and `price` also doesn't sound ideal. There should also be multiple of these timetables (different per employee / role).

Does anyone have any advice on storing this?

Comment: So I'm seeing a gap at the end - 40 minutes will cost me €58 and anything 45 minutes or more will cost €63?.  What does 41 minutes cost and what would 65 minutes cost?

Comment: Essentially everything always gets rounded up, so 12 minutes would give you €23, but everything above 40 minutes is counted as €63. I'll clarify in the question

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Are these flat charges or rates?

Comment: They are flat charges. If only they were simple rates

Answer (score 2):

Store it in a way that makes sense, which is to say ignore the interval approach and just store the breakpoints like such:

```
Role        | MaxMinuteAmt      | Cost
Plumber     | 10                | 16
Plumber     | 15                | 23
Plumber     | 40                | 58
Plumber     | 32767             | 63
```

The primary key for this table is `(Role,MaxMinuteAmt)`.  This prevents any data integrity issues with improperly entered intervals and assists in the quick lookup of the appropriate value.

To return the appropriate `Cost`, you would use the following query (which can be hardened into a stored procedure):

```
SELECT
  EmpRoleCost.Cost
FROM
  EmployeeRoleCost EmpRoleCost
WHERE
  EmpRoleCost.Role = 'Plumber'
    AND EmpRoleCost.MaxMinuteAmt =
      (
        SELECT
          MIN(MaxMinuteAmt)
        FROM
          EmployeeRoleCost
        WHERE
          Role = EmpRoleCost.Role
            AND MaxMinuteAmt >= <Number of Minutes>
      )
```

So if we query with a duration of 1 minute, the minimum value greater than or equal to that value is 10 and so on. Anything over 40 minutes up to the maximum `SMALLINT` value would return the same value (you could go with a larger datatype if needed).

This is assuming that anything up to 32,767 minutes would be charged €63, but my guess is there's probably some fixed rate once you get above a certain value (say 60 minutes).  In that case you'd change the above table to:

```
Role        | MaxMinuteAmt      | Cost
Plumber     | 10                | 16
Plumber     | 15                | 23
Plumber     | 40                | 58
Plumber     | 60                | 63
```

And create a second table to store the rate for amounts over, along with the duration of the rate (let's say 15 minutes for this example):

```
Role        | MinuteAmt     | Rate
Plumber     | 15            | 15.75
```

Then we'd change the query to utilize that rate if no flat cost is found:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE
    (
      EmpRoleCost.Cost
     ,EmpOverage.Rate * CEILING(<Actual number of minutes>/EmpOverage.MinuteAmt)
    ) AS Cost
FROM
  EmployeeRole EmployeeRole
LEFT JOIN
  EmployeeRoleOverageRate EmpOverage
    ON EmpOverage.Role = EmployeeRole.Role
LEFT JOIN
  EmployeeRoleCost EmpRoleCost
    ON EmpRoleCost.Role = EmployeeRole.Role
        AND EmpRoleCost.MaxMinuteAmt =
          (
            SELECT
              MIN(MaxMinuteAmt)
            FROM
              EmployeeRoleCost
            WHERE
              Role = EmployeeRole.Role
                AND MaxMinuteAmt >= <Number of Minutes>
          )
WHERE
  EmployeeRole.Role = 'Plumber'
```

So in this case if the number of minutes was 65, the cost would be €78.75 (`CEILING(65/15) * 15.75`).

See [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d699bd/6) Fiddle.

Comment: Thank you very much! Keeping it relatively simple is probably the best idea, the query example is much appreciated!

Comment: Your first query does seem to break on amounts larger than 45 (minutes)... I tested it on [a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c7db4/4)

Comment: @Epse - that's because you would need to use the first pattern (setting the highest rate using the largest value for the datatype).  See the Fiddle in my updated answer.